firebase cloud messaging in chrome extension v3 through gcm or firebase sdk
I have a chrome extension v3 where I need to receive push notifications for which I am using Firebase Chrome extension. I have created a project on firebase console for the same. For sending push notification from console I require registration token, which I am unable to achieve.
Below is the manifest
  "name": "Notifications",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "gcm"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}

And following is my background.js code
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details) => {
    const senderIds = ['****'];

    chrome.gcm.register(senderIds, (registrationId) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(`Registration failed: ${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Registration ID:', registrationId);
    });
});

But I always receive this error in service worker
Asynchronous operation is pending
Also tried through firebase sdk
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "FCM Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "notifications", "storage" ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
    //"type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "firebase-messaging-sw.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/icon.png"
  }
}

and background.js as
importScripts('firebase/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('firebase/firebase-messaging-compat.js');


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*",
    authDomain: "*",
    projectId: "*",
    storageBucket: "*",
    messagingSenderId: "*",
    appId: "*",
    measurementId: "*"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

console.log('here');
// Retrieve Firebase Messaging object
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log(messaging);

async function fetchToken() {
    try {
        const token = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '*************' }); 
        console.log('FCM Token:', token);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting token:', error);
    }
}

fetchToken();


I tried installing firebase locally but couldn't refer functions
inside
I also tried using static firebase files but manifest loading failed due to bad imports and then after adding module type in service worker I got error that browser doesn't support it.
Also tried bundling background through webpack
Finally after loading firebase app and messaging js (version 9.0.0) compat version locally in a folder inside my chrome extension I was able to retrieve messaging object with the above mentioned code, but still getToken function wasn't working from messaging.js

